# selecting list element with mousewheel scroll

Tags: jquery, html-lists, mousewheel

I was looking to select the li when dom listen the mousewheel so that jquery remove a class on only one and change its class then wait for next scroll, then select next one and do the same. But my code is selecting all of them and changing classes at once.

```
function scrollMe (){
  $('.header').on('mousewheel', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var scrolled = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    if(scrolled < 0){
      $('li').each(function(i){
        if($('li').hasClass('no-show')){
          $('li').removeClass('no-show').addClass('is-visible');
        }
      });
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reveal one element per scroll, knowing the scroll event fires like 10 times per single spin...
You have to buffer the events in some way.

A [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) can be used in conjunction with a flag.
Look the comments in code for details.

```js
var timer;

// This is a flag to know if we scrolled.
var scrolling=false;

$('.header').on('mousewheel', function(e){

  // Get the scrolling direction
  var scrolled = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;

  if(scrolled < 0 && !scrolling){ // if scroll down for the first time for at least 1 second.

    // Show the first hidden li found
    $('li.no-show').first().removeClass('no-show').addClass('is-visible');
  }

  // As long as user scrolls, 
  // he clears the timer
  clearTimeout(timer);

  // and sets a new one (delaying more...).
  timer = setTimeout(function(){

    // After at least 1 second not scrolling, reset the flag.
    scrolling=false;
  },1000);

  // Set the flag to know we just scrolled.
  scrolling=true;

});
```

```css
.header{
  height:300px;
  background-color:#ddd;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
.no-show{
  display:none;
}
.is-visible{
  display:list-item;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li class="no-show">2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li class="no-show">4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li class="no-show">6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li class="no-show">8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li class="no-show">10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks I spent so much so on this issue cannot figure it out that solution will be that easy thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Inside loop, you are controlling any 'li' element which has no-show class. By doing the change below, it will look for each 'li' element and do process for each one.

```
function scrollMe (){
$('.header').on('mousewheel', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var scrolled = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    if(scrolled < 0){
        $('li').each(function(i){
            if($(this).hasClass('no-show')){
            $(this).removeClass('no-show').addClass('is-visible');
            }});
    }
})
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you add an explanation to your code that explains why this answers the question. Just posting code that looks almost identical to the sample in the question, may not be enough to convince people that this answer is correct.

Comment: And you just posted the same exact code as OP...  That can't be an answer.

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette exact code? just have a text compare tool and compare both codes.

Comment: If an answer needs to be compared with a "compare tool", that is obviously not a great answer. [**Please read**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). And just changing `$('li')` for `$(this)` doesn't answer OP question at all. I wish I could downvote a second time...

Comment: Absence of a dot or semi-colon or a character might lead to compile error. And when you compare working version of this code and nonworking of the code, it will be almost same, except that tiny dot ha? So, won't it be a great answer to detect this error?

Comment: You also have to read the question to make a great answer. *«...remove a class on only one and change its class then wait for next scroll...»*